# New HttpSession is created on LinkedIn Oauth Callback

Tags: gwt, servlets

I am using `GWT` on my client side and calling a `Http Servlet` (registration servlet) dedicated for oauth login.

Once user clicks Sign-in button on page, I call a post method of registration servlet to get authorization url and store some parameters in session.

I have defined path of same registration servlet as callback url for LinkedIn Authentification. Hence as soon as user completes registration on linkedin, linkedIn page calls get method of same registration servlet. But sometimes i get the  different session in the get method  and sometimes  the same session. I need the original session to be able to retrieved the saved parameters.

Somebody suggested in this post that we can pass `JSessionID` in callback url as parameter. But still problem remains of retrieving the Session object from that JSessionID.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, instead of an answer is more than another approach.

In my last project we had the same scenario: OAuth, Servlets doing things, Sessions with some params...

We used Spring Security for this management and it worked fine. The configuration is not too much complicated...

Have you tried with it?